# Variety eating up memory and cpu

Tags: desktop-background, memory-leak

I am using Ubuntu 16.04,  64 bit,  2gb ram.  I intalled variety and using for last two months and it was working fine. But recently my system after bootup was not responding. The top command showing 'convert'  is using nearly 1gb of memory and 90% of cpu.  I identified that variety is calling convert command.  After I uninstalled variety the problem is gone. Came back again after reinstall. Cleaning cache did not work.  Help me to use variety as it was before.

Answer (score 0):

`convert` is a part of imagemagick. Try reinstalling all packages related to it that you have installed - may be one of them got damaged or wrong-linked.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Previously I was trying to install variety manually using apt install, but when I installed from market it worked. Possibly some packages got missed while manual install.

Comment: What do you mean by "installed from market"?