# Variety and convert loads up all cpu

Tags: desktop-background, cpu-load, variety

As reported in [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/829359/variety-eating-up-memory-and-cpu) question, when changing wallpaper, the application 'Variety' eats all my CPUs computational power, and makes everything lag. 
Tried reinstalling variety (also from the market) and reinstalling 'imagemagic', but none of them worked.
Help?
[image]

Additional info:

```
lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    core-9.20170808ubuntu1-noarch:printing- 9
.20170808ubuntu1-noarch:security-9.20170808ubuntu1-noarch
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
```

Comment: I ran into some bugs with Variety a couple years ago. I simply stopped using it. Eye candy is nice but when it interrupts my life too much I have to cut it loose.